# Splitting Large Dataset into multiple tabs by column

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to split a large data set (15 columns by 360,000+ rows) into multiple tabs by values inside a column in excel. I am currently using the following script, but the macro is not seemingly able to handle the amount of data (excel freezes). I have used the script on a shortened version of the data and it works perfectly. Any advice for such a large dataset would be great.

```
Sub SplitData()
Const NameCol = "O"
Const HeaderRow = 1
Const FirstRow = 2
Dim SrcSheet As Worksheet
Dim TrgSheet As Worksheet
Dim SrcRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim TrgRow As Long
Dim Student As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set SrcSheet = ActiveSheet
LastRow = SrcSheet.Cells(SrcSheet.Rows.Count, NameCol).End(xlUp).Row
For SrcRow = FirstRow To LastRow
    Student = SrcSheet.Cells(SrcRow, NameCol).Value
    Set TrgSheet = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set TrgSheet = Worksheets(Student)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TrgSheet Is Nothing Then
        Set TrgSheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
        TrgSheet.Name = Student
        SrcSheet.Rows(HeaderRow).Copy Destination:=TrgSheet.Rows(HeaderRow)
    End If
    TrgRow = TrgSheet.Cells(TrgSheet.Rows.Count, NameCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    SrcSheet.Rows(SrcRow).Copy Destination:=TrgSheet.Rows(TrgRow)
Next SrcRow
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Please add the version of Excel that you are using as there are some differences/constraints between versions.

Comment: Just curious, is it actually freezing up or may be just taking a while to run?  ScreenUpdating is being set to false so you're not actually seeing anything take place.  Even setting it to true from the beginning with that large amount of data it may still seem to freeze up.

Comment: This can be easily fastened using `Unique Collection` and `Autofilter`

Comment: If you are using xl2007+ then instead of `Unique Collection`, create a temp sheet and copy the values from `NameCol` into a new sheet and then use Remove Duplicates to get the final name of the worksheet that needs to be created.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comments, you can speed up the entire code if you use `.RemoveDuplicates` and `.AutoFilter`

**Logic**: The logic is to copy the data from Col 15 ("O") to a new sheet. Let's say Col A. Now use `.RemoveDuplicates` to delete all duplicate values. Now once that is done, you have unique names for the worksheet. Simply check if those sheet names exist in a loop and if they don't then create all the sheets in **ONE GO**.

After the sheets are created, simply use `Autofilter` to filter out the data based on sheet names which can be picked from the temp sheet. With this you don't need to loop through every row. You can do a **MASS COPYING** and it will be faster than copying every row :)

**Code (UNTESTED)**

I quickly wrote this code and hence it is not tested. Do let me know if you get any errors. I have commented the code so you shouldn't have any problem understanding it.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, colNo As Long, i As Long
    Dim NameCol As String, strCriteria As String
    Dim MyRange As Range

    NameCol = "O"

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Add Temp sheet
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    Set wsTemp = ActiveSheet

    With ws
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, NameCol).End(xlUp).Row
        colNo = .Range(NameCol & 1).Column

        '~~> Copy the column to temp sheet
        .Columns(colNo).Copy wsTemp.Columns(1)

        Set MyRange = .Range("A1:O" & lRow)
    End With

    With wsTemp
        '~~> Remove duplicates
        .Columns(1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lRow
            '~~> Check if the sheet exists
            If Not SheetExists(.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
                '~~> Create New Sheet
                 ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = (.Cells(i, 1).Value)
            End If
        Next i
    End With


    With ws
        '~~> Loop though the sheet names in the temp sheet
        For i = 2 To lRow
            strCriteria = wsTemp.Cells(i, 1)

            'Remove any filters
            .AutoFilterMode = False

            '~~> Filter range and do mass copying to relevant sheet
            With MyRange
                .AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=strCriteria

                .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strCriteria).Rows(1)
            End With

            'Remove any filters
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        Next i
    End With

    '~~> Delete Temp sheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wsTemp.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub

'~~> Function to check if the sheet exists
Function SheetExists(sName As String) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not sht Is Nothing Then SheetExists = True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

With an unsorted record set these things can take a very long time.  Excel works much faster on sorted records, and not only that you can copy much larger chunks than 1 record at a time.  Try this:

```
Sub SplitData()

Const NameCol = "O"
Const HeaderRow = 1
Const FirstRow = 2
Dim SrcSheet As Worksheet
Dim TrgSheet As Worksheet
Dim SrcRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim TrgRow As Long
Dim Student As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set SrcSheet = ActiveSheet
LastRow = SrcSheet.Cells(SrcSheet.Rows.Count, NameCol).End(xlUp).Row

'Sort first
Cells.Sort Key1:=Range(NameCol & "2"), Header:=xlYes

For SrcRow = FirstRow To LastRow

    'Get student name
    Student = SrcSheet.Cells(SrcRow, NameCol).Value

    'Gets first and last rows of that student's records
    startCopy = Columns(NameCol).Find(What:=Student, After:=Cells(1, NameCol), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
    endCopy = Columns(NameCol).Find(What:=Student, After:=Cells(LastRow + 1, NameCol), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row

    'Create a sheet for that student, once only
    Set TrgSheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    TrgSheet.Name = Student

    'Copy the header data on that sheet
    SrcSheet.Rows(HeaderRow).Copy Destination:=TrgSheet.Rows(HeaderRow)

    'Copy the student records over
    SrcSheet.Rows(SrcRow).Copy Destination:=TrgSheet.Rows(2)

    'Move the "srcRow" cursor to the last record of the found student
    SrcRow = endCopy
Next SrcRow
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I haven't tested it but it seems like this would work pretty well.

This economizes quite a lot by moving things a fraction of the time, and eliminates the extra overhead of searching for whether a student sheet has been created yet or not.